# Draw a plot using R that represent variation compared to a first value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, reshape2

I am making some small tests for the speed of execution of a program. I have a fixed size table, and the table get filled with random numbers and get sorted by an algorithm.
My tests vary the number of threads used to sort this table. Here is a sample of the results I output :

```
size;time;nb_thread;run_id
100000;0.013522;1;1
100000;0.013639;1;2
100000;0.013170;1;3
100000;0.012947;1;4
100000;0.012299;1;5
100000;0.012281;1;6
```

I want to display the improvement (or not) of using N threads on a chart. I am able to display the changes in execution time according to their mean, but the result is not visually speaking. You get the illusion that there is a tremendous improvement of using 2 threads instead of one, but in fact even if there is an improvement it is pretty small.

So I want to display the variation between the runs with only one thread, and then the subsequent ones.
I don't even know the name of what I am looking for. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This plot shows all the values compared to the first value.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dt, aes(x = factor(run_id), y = time)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = time[1]), color = "blue", size = 2) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = factor(run_id), yend = time[1]),
               size = 1, color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Run ID") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Time") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "size;time;nb_thread;run_id
100000;0.013522;1;1
                 100000;0.013639;1;2
                 100000;0.013170;1;3
                 100000;0.012947;1;4
                 100000;0.012299;1;5
                 100000;0.012281;1;6",
                 header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```